# Interpolating frequencies

Tags: c++, math, sampling

This is more of a math problem than a programming problem, but it has now come up for me twice in two different programming projects.

I would like to create a function, `w_sweep(t, f0, t0, f1, t1)`, that samples at time `t` a sine wave that sweeps through frequencies from `f0` when `t == t0` to `f1` when `t == t1`.  (You can assume frequencies are in Hz and times are in seconds.  I don't care what happens when `t` is outside the range `t0..t1`.)

I started by writing a simpler function that uses a constant frequency:

```
float w_steady(float t, float freq) {
  return std::sin(2.0f * PI * freq * t);
}
```

Intuitively, it seems like `w_sweep` would just involve linear interpolation of the frequency.

```
// INCORRECT SOLUTION
float w_sweep(float t, float f0, float t0, float f1, float t1) {
  const float freq = std::lerp(f0, f1, (t - t0)/(t1 - t0));
  return std::sin(2.0f * PI * freq * t);
}
```

At first look, the result seems correct:  The frequency is indeed `f0` in the vicinity of `t0` and then it starts to sweep toward `f1`.  But by the time you reach `t1`, the actual waveform will have overshot `f1` by quite a bit.

I think what's happening is that, instead of sweeping through the frequencies linearly with `t`, we're actually going at `t*t`, since `t` is a factor in the argument and a factor in `freq`.  Another way to think of it is that each sample is drawn from a different wave function.  They're all sine waves at different constant frequencies.  But they aren't really correlated (except at time 0, when all of them will give the same value).

If I wanted to create sequential samples with a loop, I could solve the problem by accumulating the position along the sign wave.

```
float omega = 0;
for (float t = t0; t <= t1; t += dt) {
  samples.push_back(std::sin(omega));
  const float freq = std::lerp(f0, f1, (t - t0)/(t1 - t0));
  omega += 2.0f * PI * freq * dt;
}
```

That works, but I'd prefer a `w_sweep` that it can be sampled at arbitrary times.

Comment: If the frequency is not constant, it's not a sinewave.

Comment: It seems that what you want to do is a [chirp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp).

Comment: see [Find start point (time) of each cycle in a sine wave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37583214/2521214) btw just curious what kind of programming projects? I encounter problems like this in signal generators and CNC and robotics motion control ...

Comment: @EOF:  I open to learning better terminology.  It's a sweep based on a sine function, as opposed to one based on a square wave, saw tooth, or triangle.  Damien's suggestion of "chirp" is closer than I thought.  I thought chirps were specifically sweeps over very short intervals, but the Wikipedia suggests they are more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think about it in terms of *phase*. For a constant frequency the *phase* ist just the product of *time* and *frequency*. But in general it's the integral over the *frequency function* across *time*.

The easiest way to show how this works is with a diagram, but its also possible with formal math. Unfortunately SO markdown neither supports graphs nor latex markdown. But if work it through, the result is:

```
float w_sweep(float t, float f0, float t0, float f1, float t1) {
  float const freq = std::lerp(f0, f1, (t - t0)/(t1 - t0));
  return std::sin(PI * (f0 + freq) * (t-t0));
}
```

The graphical approch can be described as follows:
The phase is area under the frequency function in time, covered since `t0`. For our example it is best to split it into a rectangular area at the base `f0*(t-t0)` and a triangular area on top `0.5*(freq-f0)*(t-t0)`. Multiply the sum by 2π and you get `PI * (f0 + freq) * (t-t0)`.

Comment: It seems the good approach. However, according to me, it must be `return std::sin(PI * freq * (t-t0));` simply.

Comment: Yes!  My iterative solution is effectively doing a numeric integration.  So the random access solution involves the integral.  Nicely explained!

Answer (score 0):

It can be wise to look at the reverse, the change in periods. For a frequency f0, you have a period T0 = 1/f0. For a frequency f1, you have a period T1=1/f1.

Now, when you evaluate `w_sweep(t)`, you're not using one period T0, then a period `lerp(T0,T1,...)` etcetera. Instead, you determine a single period `T = 1.0/std::lerp(f0, f1, (t - t0)/(t1 - t0))`, and then calculate `sin(2*pi*t/T)` which is of course `sin(2*pi*frac(t/T))`.

I think what you want (not entirely sure) is `f=1/lerp(1/f0, 1/f1, (t - t0)/(t1 - t0))`

Comment: I did mess around with an approach based on the period, but I believe it works out to the same problem:  There's a cumulative error in the phase if you just try to interpolate either frequency or period.