# Sine-Tone generator produces undesired harmonics

Tags: math, audio-streaming, audiowaveform

I am writing a program to generate sinewave audio tones at 44.1khz sampling rate.  The 2 plots below contain 720 audio samples on the X axis and a sine wave that goes between +/-4000 on the Y axis (4000 represents the amplitude/volume in this case).

The contents of the 720 sample sine wave (1,440 bytes of PCM 16 signed audio) are sent as back to back datagrams to an audio application where it should reproduce a pure test tone.  In order for a pure tone, I need to produce the lower plot (I have to adjust the frequency by hand until I get a continuous plot).

My questions is how do I mathematically calculate the set of valid frequencies to fit the above.

This is how I produced the above plots:

```cpp
// check sampleRate, channelCount and sampleFormat
if (rAudioFormat.isValid()) {
    const auto sampleFormat = rAudioFormat.sampleFormat();
    const auto channelCount = rAudioFormat.channelCount();
    const auto bytesPerFrame = rAudioFormat.bytesPerFrame();
    const auto volume = aVolumePercent / 100.0f;
    // payload must have room for at least 1 frame
    if (aAudioSizeBytes >= bytesPerFrame) {
        static std::default_random_engine gRandomNumberGenerator;
        // each frame contains inputChannelCount audio samples
        const qint64 frameCount = aAudioSizeBytes / bytesPerFrame;
        // pad size in bytes at the end of the datagram.
        const qint64 paddingBytes = aAudioSizeBytes % bytesPerFrame;
        // allocate raw data for an unpadded audio sample
        const auto payload = std::make_unique<char[]>(aAudioSizeBytes - paddingBytes);
        switch (aSignalGenerator) {
        case SignalGenerator::Monotone:
            {
                if ((!rGeneratorParams.empty()) &&
                    (static_cast<size_t>(rAudioFormat.sampleRate()) > 0u)) {
                    const auto frequency = rGeneratorParams[0];
                    for (auto t = 0; t < frameCount; ++t) {
                        const auto value = qSin(
                            2 * M_PI * frequency * (t % frameCount) /
                            rAudioFormat.sampleRate());
                        switch (sampleFormat) {
                        . . .
                        case QAudioFormat::SampleFormat::Int16:
                            {
                                constexpr auto gMaxVal = std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::max();
                                const auto dest = reinterpret_cast<int16_t*>(payload.get());
                                for (auto i = 0; i < channelCount; i++) {
                                    dest[t * channelCount + i] =
                                        static_cast<int16_t>(gMaxVal * volume * value);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
```

[image: Pair of audio plots, upper produces harmonics, lower produces desired pure tone]

So far, I have come up with the following bit of code which does part of the job (I think). I know I need get the even (as it needs to fit a sine) divisors of 720, but I don't quite know how to complete this code to return the frequency values corresponding to each of the divisors.  Given the sampling rate, I should probably also consider nyquist to limit the maximum reproducible tone frequency.

```cpp
    //! helper function to calculate produce pure tones
    //! given nTotalSamples with given nSampleRate.
    std::vector<int> getDivisors(int nSampleRate, int nTotalSamples, int nearestMin) {
        std::vector<int> divisors;
        if ((nSampleRate> 0) && (nearestMin > 0) &&
            (nearestMin <= nTotalSamples)) {
            for (int i = nearestMin; i < nTotalSamples; ++i) {
                if ((nTotalSamples % i) == 0) {
                    // calculate the corresponding tone frequency
                    divisors.emplace_back(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return divisors;
    }
```

Comment: If your question is how to "*mathematically calculate the set of valid frequencies to fit the above.*" then you may be off topic here. Because this site is about programming problems and not math problems ...

Comment: @derpirscher I did add math to the tag list as you an see.

Comment: Have you also read the description of the math-tag? "*For general math questions, please ask on math.stackexchange.com*" And so far, your problem seems to be to get the math right rather than implementing the formula correctly ...

Comment: @derpirscher no this is not about math, its about digital signal processing DSP and still fits this site (at 
least from my point of view)...

Answer (score 1):

Your frame duration is number of samples divided by sample rate. The number of oscillations is frequency times duration. You want that to be an integer. So simply compute the number you would get, then round that to the nearest integer and convert back to a frequency:

```
double frameDuration = samplesPerFrame / sampleRate;
double fractionalOscillations = frameDuration * desiredFrequency;
double wholeOscillations = round(fractionalOscillations);
double goodFrequency = wholeOscillations / frameDuration;
```

Note I'm using `double` so I don't have to worry about any rounding effects along the way. This could lead to each individual oscillation taking a fractional number of samples. The way you compute your individual values – by just feeding an argument to a sine function – I would not expect this to be a problem.

Also note that you have to use compatible units. If you use sample rate as samples per second, and frequency as Hz, that works fine since both have unit `1/s`.

Comment: good idea thinking in terms of oscillations that fit in the 720 samples available in the datagram.  If I determine the divisors of 720 (using the sample code I wrote), I should be able to convet these divisors to frequencies - so considering the trivial example where a single oscillation corresponds to a divisor of 720 - this would correspond to a tone of 44.1khz / 720 (i.e. 62.5 Hz - unaudible), the other divisors for 720 are {360, 240, 180, 144, 120, 90, 80, 72, 60, 48, ... 1}.  Athough these frequencies are not integers, I can generate exact perfect tones using these divisors.

Comment: No need to restrict yourself to integral number of samples per oscillation. You can fit 7 complete oscillations if each oscillation takes 102.8571 samples, for a frequency of 428.75Hz. Also not sure where the 62.5Hz in your comment is coming from. 44100Hz/720=61.25Hz so you could get any multiple of that.

Comment: my calculation was a typo.  BTW It seems you are a fellow dubliner :)

Answer (score 0):

with continuous signal synthesis there are 2 major problems:

1. **aliasing**

   in case your `f` frequency is not exact integer divisor of sampling frequency `fsampling` the output will alias to 2 frequencies one slightly smaller and one slightly bigger than your desired frequency and they will alternate ...

   to avoid this you can round output frequency to integer divisor of sampling frequency so:

   ```cpp
   f' = fsampling/floor(fsampling/f) // or ceil or round
   ```
2. **fixed (finite) buffer size**

   so you have a 720 samples in your buffer but you have to use it as infinite (ring FIFO) buffer so if periods of your signal is not exact divisor of buffer size you have to remember the phase of last sample and continue next buffer from that point ...

   see: [Find start point (time) of each cycle in a sine wave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37583214/2521214)

   If you don't then it will create glitches on joint with the next buffer producing usually many many more (even higher) frequencies...

   In case you are **sending just single buffer that should loop itself** then you have to round your frequency `f` period `T` (in the same manner as above) to be integer divisor of buffer duration period `Tbuffer`...

   ```cpp
   Tbuffer = samples / fsampling
   T = 1/f
   T' = Tbuffer/floor(Tbuffer/T) // or ceil or round
   f' = 1/T'
   ```

   this will also avoid the alias problem from previous bullet as `Tbuffer` is multiple of `Tsampling`...

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, however I believe I adressed most of these issues.  (1) Aliasing: firstly the first sample is always 0.  The divisors of 720 (shown in my example code) - represent full sine wave cycles that start at 0 phase and end at one sampling inverval prior to phase 0 on sample 720 (index 719), for this reason the plot/datagram will always contain an exact set of cycles which when transmitted back to back will produce a continuous sinewave.  (it does as I have that working). (2) fixed buffer size: as the signal is continuous described in (1) no need for FIFO.

Comment: @johnco3  1. fixed size single looping buffer and 2. infinite (dual) ring FIFO are just two ways of doing things with their pros and cons the 1. needs to be computed and send just once but you have to align your signal period to buffer duration 2. needs synchronization (to avoid overun/underun problems) and need continuous traffic  but have much better acuracy of signal period as it need to align to sample rate which is much smaller than buffer duration ... or if you allow phase jitter along with frequency aliasing it might not be aligned at all allowing "any" frequency to be generated ...

Comment: Hello Spektre, can you join this chat with me ? 
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257168/reverse-engineer-mcp2000-lcd-spektre
I hope you are doing fine